# balanced payments with django

Tags: python, django, python-requests, balanced-payments

Hi I installed the following python library:
https://github.com/balanced/balanced-python

When I use that library to charge a credit card as follows in my django code:

```
buyer = balanced.Marketplace.my_marketplace.create_buyer(
                    user_email, card_uri=card_uri)
```

I get the following error:

```
request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'config'
```

It seems to be a problem with my csrf protection.

What can I do to fix this error?

Here is pip freeze:

```
Django==1.4.5
PIL==1.1.7
South==0.7.6
amqp==1.0.8
anyjson==0.3.3
argparse==1.2.1
balanced==0.10.0
billiard==2.7.3.21
boto==2.8.0
celery==3.0.15
certifi==0.0.8
chardet==1.0.1
cssmin==0.1.4
django-annoying==0.7.7
django-balanced==0.1.9
django-celery==3.0.11
django-celery-with-redis==3.0
django-debug-toolbar==0.9.4
django-extensions==1.1.0
django-model-utils==1.2.0
django-notifications-hq==0.5.5
django-storages==1.1.6
django-taggit==0.9.3
djangorestframework==2.2.1
djrill==0.3.1
gdata==2.0.17
iso8601==0.1.4
kombu==2.5.6
mock==1.0.1
odict==1.5.1
ply==3.4
psycopg2==2.4.6
python-dateutil==1.5
python-memcached==1.48
pytz==2012j
redis==2.7.2
requests==1.1.0
simplejson==2.3.2
six==1.2.0
slimit==0.7.4
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

trackback error:

```
ile "//env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

  File "//env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 48, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "//env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 77, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "//env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 393, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)

  File "//env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 390, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "//env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 41, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "//cr/api/views.py", line 403, in order_bid_detail
    buyer = balanced.Marketplace.my_marketplace.create_buyer(

  File "//env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/balanced/utils.py", line 203, in __get__
    return self.fget.__get__(obj, klass)()

  File "//env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/balanced/resources.py", line 717, in wrapped
    cached = f(*args, **kwargs)

  File "//env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/balanced/resources.py", line 867, in my_marketplace
    return cls.query.one()

  File "//env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/balanced/resources.py", line 163, in one
    ret = list(self[0:2])

  File "//env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/balanced/resources.py", line 98, in __getitem__
    res = self._slice(start, stop)

  File "//env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/balanced/resources.py", line 118, in _slice
    self.qs['offset'] = (self.offset or 0) + start

  File "//env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/balanced/resources.py", line 203, in offset
    return self._lazy_loaded['offset']

  File "//env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/balanced/utils.py", line 189, in __get__
    value = self.func(obj)

  File "//env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/balanced/resources.py", line 177, in _lazy_loaded
    response = Resource.http_client.get(page.uri)

  File "//env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/balanced/http_client.py", line 117, in make_absolute_url
    return http_op(client, url, **kwargs)

  File "//env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/balanced/http_client.py", line 139, in get
    resp = self.interface.get(uri, **kwargs)

  File "//env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 310, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)

TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'config'
```

Comment: are you doing a configuration of balance before calling it? `balanced.configure(SECRETKEY)`

Comment: paste the stacktrace for the error. it sounds like the problem is in the requests library if memory serves. also, give us the output of `pip freeze`

Comment: added stracktrace and pip freeze

Comment: Seems to be the recent version of requests is causing this problem, but when I downgraded my requests package, I no longer have that problem... thanks.

Comment: Hi Jewelwast, there's a branch that is using the most recent version of requests. I can help you with this on irc.freenode.net #balanced.